# Segfault when import_array not in same translation unit

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I'm having problems getting the NumPy C API to properly initialize. I think I've isolated the problem to calling `import_array` from a different translation unit, but I don't know why this should matter.

Minimal working example:

**header1.hpp**

```
#ifndef HEADER1_HPP
#define HEADER1_HPP
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/npy_3kcompat.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

void initialize();

#endif
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#include "header1.hpp"

void* wrap_import_array()
{
  import_array();
  return (void*) 1;
}

void initialize()
{
  wrap_import_array();
}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "header1.hpp"

#include <iostream>

void* loc_wrap_import_array()
{
  import_array();
  return (void*) 1;
}

void loc_initialize()
{
  loc_wrap_import_array();
}

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();
#ifdef USE_LOC_INIT
  loc_initialize();
#else
  initialize();
#endif
  npy_intp dims[] = {5};
  std::cout << "creating descr" << std::endl;
  PyArray_Descr* dtype = PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_FLOAT64);
  std::cout << "zeros" << std::endl;
  PyArray_Zeros(1, dims, dtype, 0);
  std::cout << "cleanup" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler commands:

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp -o segissue -lpython3.4m -I/usr/include/python3.4m -DUSE_LOC_INIT
./segissue
# runs fine

g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp -o segissue -lpython3.4m -I/usr/include/python3.4m
./segissue
# segfaults
```

I've tested this with Clang 3.6.0, GCC 4.9.2, Python 2.7, and Python 3.4 (with a suitably modified `wrap_import_array` because this is different between Python 2.x and 3.x). The various combinations all give the same result: if I don't call `loc_initialize`, the program will segfault in the `PyArray_DescrFromType` call. I have NumPy version 1.8.2. For reference, I'm running this in Ubuntu 15.04.

What baffles me most of all is [this C++ NumPy wrapper](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy) appears to get away with calling `import_array` in a different translation unit.

What am I missing? Why must I call `import_array` from the same translation unit in order for it to actually take effect? More importantly, how do I get it to work when I call `import_array` from a different translation unit like the Boost.NumPy wrapper does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging through the NumPy headers, I think I've found a solution:

in `numpy/__multiarray_api.h`, there's a section dealing with where an internal API buffer should be. For conciseness, here's the relevant snippet:

```
#if defined(PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL)
#define PyArray_API PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL
#endif

#if defined(NO_IMPORT) || defined(NO_IMPORT_ARRAY)
extern void **PyArray_API;
#else
#if defined(PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL)
void **PyArray_API;
#else
static void **PyArray_API=NULL;
#endif
#endif
```

It looks like this is intended to allow multiple modules define their own internal API buffer, in which each module must call their own `import_array` define.

A consistent way to get several translation units to use the same internal API buffer is in every module, define `PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL` to some library unique name, then every translation unit *other than the one where the import_array wrapper is defined* defines `NO_IMPORT` or `NO_IMPORT_ARRAY`. Incidentally, there are similar macros for the ufunc features: `PY_UFUNC_UNIQUE_SYMBOL`, and `NO_IMPORT`/`NO_IMPORT_UFUNC`.

The modified working example:

**header1.hpp**

```
#ifndef HEADER1_HPP
#define HEADER1_HPP

#ifndef MYLIBRARY_USE_IMPORT
#define NO_IMPORT
#endif

#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL MYLIBRARY_ARRAY_API
#define PY_UFUNC_UNIQUE_SYMBOL MYLIBRARY_UFUNC_API

#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/npy_3kcompat.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

void initialize();

#endif
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#define MYLIBRARY_USE_IMPORT
#include "header1.hpp"

void* wrap_import_array()
{
  import_array();
  return (void*) 1;
}

void initialize()
{
  wrap_import_array();
}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "header1.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  initialize();
  npy_intp dims[] = {5};
  std::cout << "creating descr" << std::endl;
  PyArray_Descr* dtype = PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_FLOAT64);
  std::cout << "zeros" << std::endl;
  PyArray_Zeros(1, dims, dtype, 0);
  std::cout << "cleanup" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know what pitfalls there are with this hack or if there are any better alternatives, but this appears to at least compile and run without any segfaults.

Comment: can you please share the definition of MYLIBRARY_ARRAY_API? Thanks.

Comment: MYLIBRARY_ARRAY_API is just an example name used for storing NumPy internal buffers. It is not a macro, but it should be unique to your application/library to prevent clashing with other libraries.