# Numpy/CAPI error with import_array() when compiling multiple modules

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy, python-c-api

I am trying to compile a C++ module to use in `scipy.weave` that is composed of several headers and source C++ files. These files contain classes and methods that extensively use the Numpy/C-API interface. But I am failing to figure out how to include `import_array()` successfully. I have been struggling on this for the past week and I am going nuts. I hope you could help me with it because the `weave` [help](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#importing-the-api) is not very explanatory.

In practice I have first a module called `pycapi_utils` that contains some routines to interface C objects with Python objects. It consists of a header file `pycapi_utils.h` and a source file `pycapi_utils.cpp` such as:

```
//pycapi_utils.h
#if ! defined _PYCAPI_UTILS_H
#define _PYCAPI_UTILS_H 1

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <list>

typedef std::tuple<const char*,PyObject*> pykeyval; //Tuple type (string,Pyobj*) as dictionary entry (key,val)
typedef std::list<pykeyval> kvlist;                    

//Declaration of methods
PyObject* array_double_to_pyobj(double* v_c, long int NUMEL); //Convert from array to Python list (double)
...
...
#endif
```

and

```
//pycapi_utils.cpp

#include "pycapi_utils.h"

PyObject* array_double_to_pyobj(double* v_c, long int NUMEL){
    //Convert a double array to a Numpy array
    PyObject* out_array = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, &NUMEL, NPY_DOUBLE);
    double* v_b = (double*) ((PyArrayObject*) out_array)->data;
    for (int i=0;i<NUMEL;i++) v_b[i] = v_c[i];
    free(v_c);
    return out_array;
}
```

Then I have a further module `model` that contains classes and routines dealing with some mathematical model. Again it consists of a header and source file like:

```
//model.h
#if ! defined _MODEL_H
#define _MODEL_H 1

//model class
class my_model{
    int i,j;
    public:
        my_model();
        ~my_model();
        double* update(double*); 
}

//Simulator   
PyObject* simulate(double* input);
#endif
```

and

```
//model.cpp

#include "pycapi_utils.h"
#include "model.h"

//Define class and methods
model::model{
...
...
}

...
...

double* model::update(double* input){
    double* x = (double*)calloc(N,sizeof(double));
    ...
    ...

    // Do something
    ...
    ...

    return x;
}

PyObject* simulate(double* input){
    //Initialize Python interface 
    Py_Initialize;
    import_array();

    model random_network;
    double* output;

    output = random_network.update(input);
    return array_double_to_pyobj(output);  // from pycapi_utils.h     
}
```

The above code is included in a `scipy.weave` module in Python with

```
def model_py(input):
    support_code="""
                 #include "model.h"
                 """
    code = """
           return_val = simulate(input.data());
           """
    libs=['gsl','gslcblas','m']
    vars = ['input']
    out = weave.inline(code,
                       vars,
                       support_code=support_code,
                       sources = source_files,
                       libraries=libs
                       type_converters=converters.blitz,
                       compiler='gcc',
                       extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
                       force=1)
```

It fails to compile giving:

```
error: int _import_array() was not declared in this scope
```

Noteworthy is that if I lump into `pycapi_utils.h` also the source `pycapi_utils.cpp`, everything works fine. But I don't want to use this solution, as in practice my modules here need to be included in several other modules that also use PyObjects and need call `import_array()`.

I was looking to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971185/segfault-when-import-array-not-in-same-translation-unit) on stack exchange, but I cannot figure out if and how to properly define the `#define` directives in my case. Also the example in that post is not exactly my case as there, `import_array()` is called within the global scope of `main()` whereas in my case `import_array()` is called within my `simulate` routine which is invoked by `main()` build by `scipy.weave`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem, as the link you've posted points out, the root of all evil is that the `PyArray_API` is defined static, which means that each translation unit has it's own `PyArray_API` which is initialized with `PyArray_API = NULL` by default. Thus `import_array()` must be called once for every `*.cpp` file.  In your case it should be sufficient to call it in `pycapi_utils.cpp` and also once in `model.cpp`. You can also test if array_import is necessary before actualy calling it with:

```
if(PyArray_API == NULL)
{
    import_array(); 
}
```

Comment: Just conincidentaly found that the solution to this issue is well documented  [here in the numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/c-api.array.html#miscellaneous)

Comment: Does the link you provided advocate using a different solution from yours? 1) `import_array` only in one file, 2) use `#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL` in that file and others, 3) use `#define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY` in files not using `import_array`.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently if I include in the `pycapi_utils` module a simple initialization routine such as:

```
//pycapi_utils.h
...
...
void init_numpy();

//pycapi_utils.cpp
...
...
void init_numpy(){
    Py_Initialize;
    import_array();
}
```

and then I invoke this routine at the beginning of any function / method that uses Numpy objects in my C code, it works. That is, the above code is edited as:

```
//pycapi_utils.cpp
...
...
PyObject* array_double_to_pyobj(...){
    init_numpy();
    ...
    ...
}


//model.cpp
...
...
PyObject* simulate(...){
    init_numpy();
    ...
    ...
}
```

My only concern at this point is whether there is a way to minimize number of calls to `init_numpy()`, or regardless I have to call it from any function that I define within my CPP modules that uses Numpy objects...