# How does import_array in numpy C API work?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, c-api

I am trying to convert a c-style array in c++ to a numpy array and ran into problems when trying to use the "PyArray_SimpleNewFromData" function. It turns out I need to call

```
import_array()
```

Though I do not understand how to call this function. Whenever I try calling it I get compiler error which I do not manage to understand. For instance writing the following simple script:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

int main(){
    Py_Initialize();
    import_array();
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

produces the compiler error

> error: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]
>   import_array();

I looked at several examples, such as :

[Numpy C-Api example gives a SegFault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730717/numpy-c-api-example-gives-a-segfault/7732174#7732174)

[PyArray_SimpleNewFromData example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357115/pyarray-simplenewfromdata-example)

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92266/sending-a-c-array-to-python-numpy-and-back

[Numpy/CAPI error with import_array() when compiling multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899621/numpy-capi-error-with-import-array-when-compiling-multiple-modules)

But whatever I try (even when seemingly following those examples) I seem to run into the compiler error above. What am I missing or doing wrong? An explanation on how the import_array() function should be called would be very welcome. Thanks for the help!

Update:

I am using python 2.7.11, and I think it might be related to what is discussed here :

https://github.com/clemenscorny/brisk/issues/3

but I still have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the source code of `import_array()` from numpy, it is a macro that mainly calls the `_import_array()` regular function, and then does some weird exception handling. If you call `_import_array()` instead of `import_array()`, the compilation error disappears. And, at least in my case, the behavior is then correct (i.e. no segfault when calling Numpy C API functions)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in numpy: `import_array()` is a macro that can return `0` or `NULL` or nothing (void).

It's impossible to use in strict mode where the compiler verifies the return type of functions. A function returning an integer can't return `NULL`. A function returning a pointer can't return `0`. A function returning something can't return nothing.

There's an alternative macro to use instead `import_array1(0)`

```
int
numpy_init()
{
    import_array1(0);
    return 0;
}
```

See numpy source code `__multiarray_api.h`

```
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
#define NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL NULL
#else
#define NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL
#endif

#define import_array() {if (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL; } }

#define import_array1(ret) {if (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return ret; } }

#define import_array2(msg, ret) {if (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, msg); return ret; } }

#endif
```